# React JS Attempted import error: './Pathfinder/Pathfinder' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Pathfinder')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have had a look at a lot of different possible fixes for this but I can't. When I compile the react code I get an error saying that I need to use a default export even though I exported it through the class. I've tried just exporting the part where I call the pathfinder script and that doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Pathfinder from './Pathfinder/Pathfinder';

function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <Pathfinder></Pathfinder>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Pathfinder.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Node from './Node/Node';

import './Pathfinder.css';

function app(){
  return(
    <div>
      <p>

      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with your `Pathfinder` export in `.Pathfinder/Pathfinder.js`.

Comment: your `Pathfinder.js` doesn't have any exports at all tho you need to add something like this `export default app;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questionable things going on here, especially your having an `app` component and an `App` component. But as your error is conveying, you're not exporting the `app` component in Pathfinder.js. Dirty fix:

```
export default function app() {
    // ...
}
```

Though, at the very least, I would rename the function to `Pathfinder`.